# Getting the username in Twitter using OAuth 0.1.1 Grails plugin

Tags: grails, oauth

anyone had tried using http://www.grails.org/plugin/oauth? i'm trying it in twitter.com and i'm having an issue on getting the username or accessing this API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0verify_credentials

here's the code in my callback URL:

```
def twitterCallback = {

    def response = oauthService.accessResource('http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json','twitter', session.oauthToken)

    log.debug "response: ${response}"
}
```

i keep getting this error:

> 2010-04-22 14:32:56,842 [http-8081-1]
>   WARN  httpclient.HttpMethodBase  -
>   Cookie rejected: "$Version=0;
>   _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCMQcOCQoAToHaWQiJThiYWY4MGI1YTY1M2U0%250AYTRhNjAzYTA2NTBmNjkzZTYwIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--31d191141bf32e0489967492692f1e77fc9e1845;
>   $Path=/; $Domain=.twitter.com".
>   Illegal domain attribute
>   ".twitter.com". Domain of origin:
>   "twitter.com" 2010-04-22 14:32:56,854
>   [http-8081-1] INFO 
>   auth.AuthChallengeProcessor  - basic
>   authentication scheme selected
>   2010-04-22 14:32:56,856 [http-8081-1]
>   INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  -
>   No credentials available for BASIC
>   'Twitter API'@twitter.com:80
>   2010-04-22 14:32:56,865 [http-8081-1]
>   ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver 
>   - null

it seems that it uses BASIC authentication instead of OAuth. any ideas? or is there an issue in the OAuth Grails plugin?

thanks.

Comment: so how did you get username after success callback?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866700/grails-oauth-twitter-userid-from-token/19866862#19866862